# How can I determine when to list hobbies/side projects on a resume when the quality might be somewhat low?

Tags: resume, job-search, skills

I am a ASP.net developer and in my free time I have created a basic JavaScript games because I'm bored/find it fun. It helps with my job as I get a better understanding and practice with JavaScript.

However I'm not sure if I should include this as a hobby in my CV as I only do it to try stuff and get experience. This results in the quality being quite amateurish. As an example, [here](http://screencast.com/t/o1SVIOWPjkJ2) is a link to one of my creations on Jing.

If I get asked about this in an interview, I think it will become obvious that the quality of my work is pretty low. I think this might cause more harm than good. But I can see this being beneficial regardless as it shows I continue to grow my skills outside work, etc.

- How can I determine when to include fun projects (which might not be high quality) on a resume?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Workplace! I edited your question slightly to make it a bit more on topic here and less specific to your situation. Feel free to [edit] if I changed your intent too much, I think I captured what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you simply advertise yourself as having a working knowledge of Javascript, showing how many years you've worked with it, and leave it at that.

At the interview level, if they ask for examples of what you've done in the past, you can mention those specifics - that you've used it to improve web application responsiveness on the job, and that you use it in your free time to develop simple games and improve your understanding of Javascript.

At the resume level, the details of your experience aren't as important as you having any at all - but when you get to the interview level, showing that you have an interest not just in using it for work, but for enjoyment and for self-improvement, they'll see in the interview someone who's really dedicated to code-writing.

Answer (score 1):

Any of your skills is welcome on a cv as it shows you have interests and invest yourself in activities instead of being passive.

Showing that you are an active and invested person is extremely important in a cv and therefore advantageous under any form.

You could put it under "Working Knowledge" as it means you have a low-level competency in an area, which means you could work in it without being an expert in the field.

Just don't exaggerate it or undermine your skills.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect an employer to use information you've listed under hobbies or 'outside of work' activities to determine whether you're the right candidate for the vacancy, especially if it isn't a direct line of work with the job being applied for.

There are huge benefits in detailing any interests you have or recreational activities no matter how insignificant you feel they may be. This gives insight into you as a character to a potential employer and a lot can be learned from this. And as you state, another benefit can be that it shows you continue to develop or extend your skillset outside work.

As long as you clearly state your level of knowledge with this particular use of working with JavaScript and that your skills in developing basic JavaScript games are still in their infancy then I don't expect this to be held against you during an job application process.